# Reduce Bluetooth signal strength on Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, power-management, rssi

Is there a high-level (Java) or low-level way (using native code) to change Bluetooth signal strength on Android devices to a minimum ?

The goal is to make the device discoverable within a range of 20 centimeters ?
Can't find anything at all on Internet regarding this.

Comment: If you want to filter out devices far away when you scan, you can use the rssi parameter to get the signal strength.

Comment: RSSI is not the thing which you can use to measure accurate distance to the other device. I mean you can try but the accuracy is not so great.
As mentioned here https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html: "At close proximity of about 1 meter, you can expect to see distance estimates between 0.5-2 meters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using your custom BLE advertising on android, you can use below modes to set your bluet-tooth discovery range.

```
//Use AdvertiseSettings class

ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED : Perform Bluetooth LE advertising in balanced power mode.
ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY : Perform Bluetooth LE advertising in low latency, high power mode.
ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER : Perform Bluetooth LE advertising in low power mode.

ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_LOW : Advertise using low TX power level.

ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_ULTRA_LOW : Advertise using the lowest transmission (TX) power level.
```

Refer this for [detail](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings) documentation

Comment: Yesterday I tried ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER with ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_ULTRA_LOW. The device became discoverable within 3 meters, which is not acceptable for my goal (20 centimeters).
But you correctly answered to my question, I should probably accept it, but waiting for other comments if it's possible to control TX power using low-level way ?

Comment: You can use proximity sensors for such short distance

Comment: Wow ! That's a great idea, I'll consider this